# PHP MySQL-query results in jibberish

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a MySQL query with PDO.
I'm using `charset=utf8`.
The query finds an answer (which is supposed to be a full name).
However, the result always looks like this:

> =?UTF-8?B?*somejibber*?=

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is what I'm doing:
I'M using fmbiete's Z-Push-Contrib to get the full name of dovecot users from my ispconfig3 database.

https://github.com/fmbiete/Z-Push-contrib/blob/master/backend/imap/config.php
https://github.com/fmbiete/Z-Push-contrib/blob/master/backend/imap/imap.php

```
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbispconfig;charset=utf8');
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_USER', 'z-push');
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_PASSWORD', 'XXXYYY');
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_OPTIONS', serialize(array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)));
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_QUERY', 'select name, email from mail_user where login = "#username"');
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_FIELDS', serialize(array('name', 'email')));
define('IMAP_FROM_SQL_FROM', '#name <#email>');
```

_

```
private function getFromSql($username, $domain) {
        $from = $username;

        $dbh = $sth = $record = null;
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO(IMAP_FROM_SQL_DSN, IMAP_FROM_SQL_USER, IMAP_FROM_SQL_PASSWORD, unserialize(IMAP_FROM_SQL_OPTIONS));
            ZLog::Write(LOGLEVEL_DEBUG, sprintf("BackendIMAP->getFromSql() - Connected to SQL Database"));

            $sql = str_replace('#username', $username, str_replace('#domain', $domain, IMAP_FROM_SQL_QUERY));
            ZLog::Write(LOGLEVEL_DEBUG, sprintf("BackendIMAP->getFromSql() - Searching From with filter: %s", $sql));
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute();
            $record = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($record) {
                ZLog::Write(LOGLEVEL_DEBUG, sprintf("BackendIMAP->getFromSql() - Found entry in SQL Database. Generating From"));
                $from = IMAP_FROM_SQL_FROM;
                foreach (unserialize(IMAP_FROM_SQL_FIELDS) as $field) {
                    $from = str_replace('#'.$field, $record[$field], $from);
                }
                $from = $this->encodeFrom($from);
            }
            else {
                ZLog::Write(LOGLEVEL_DEBUG, sprintf("BackendIMAP->getFromSql() - No entry found in SQL Database"));
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) {
            ZLog::Write(LOGLEVEL_WARN, sprintf("BackendIMAP->getFromSql() - Error getting From value from SQL Database: %s", $ex));
        }

        $dbh = $sth = $record = null;

        return $from;
    }
```

**EDIT**

As @rocket-hazmat pointed out in the comments this seems to be intended behavior and is good as is – a useless thread this is ;-)

Comment: Not without seeing any code, no.

Comment: ^--« Put me in for 9 more votes.

Comment: How is this value put into the db?  How are you getting it back out?  `=?UTF-8?B?...?=` is normally used in email headers.  The `somejibber` is base64'd utf8 data.  http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1342.txt

Comment: @rocket-hazmat you are absolutely right, thank you for finding this out!

Comment: @basbebe: You're welcome.  :-)  Your IMAP class is converting your UTF8 strings into that format so that they appear properly in emails.

Comment: @rocket-hazmat thanks for your input!
So this is intentional?
Will the header then be shown correctly for the recipient?

Comment: @basbebe: Yes, it is and it will :-)

Comment: @rocket-hazmat thank you so much! Seems like I was getting crazy for nothing! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=?utf-8?B?gibberish?=` means that someone stored an information as BASE64 UTF8 ENCODED.

This is common in email systems, where the subject and the From: fields might not be in low-ASCII and not even any Western encoding at all.

So if you want to recover the information, you need to parse that value.

For example:

```
$gibberish = '=?utf-8?B?UmVuw6llIERldXhpw6htZQo=?=';

if (preg_match('#=\\?utf-8\\?B\\?(.*)\\?=#', $gibberish, $gregs)) {
    $clean = base64_decode($gregs[1]);
    // You may need to utf_decode or iconv the value to suit your needs.
} else {
    // Do not clean :-(
    $clean = $gibberish;
}

print $clean;
```

outputs

`Renée Deuxième`

As a side note, another possible encoding is Quoted-Printable UTF8, which is recognizable by the prefix `=?utf-8?Q` (note the Q instead of the B).

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong nor jibbering here.

`=?UTF-8?B?somejibber?=` is a perfectly valid value someone stored in the database. You may ask them why they did so. We cannot tell you that.

Comment: this value is not stored in the table I'm searching…

Answer (score -1):

try to set name to utf-8

```
$example->exec("set names utf8");
```